# Permanently remove Xcode provisioning profiles

Tags: ios, xcode

How do I permanently delete the provisioning profiles that Xcode creates and manages?

I tried:

- Deleting them from the Apple Developer site
- Selecting them in Xcode's Accounts settings and choosing **Move to Trash**
- Deleting the profiles on my connected iPhone, in Xcode's Devices window
- Deleting and re-adding the Apple ID from Xcode's Accounts settings.
- Making sure `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles` is empty
- Quitting and re-launching Xcode

But then when I go to Xcode's Accounts settings and click **Download All**, the deleted profiles re-appear. Where are they coming from? How do I get rid of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea if this is safe, but I deleted the files `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DeveloperPortal*`. After doing that, the profiles are no longer re-created when I click **Download All**. This worked on two separate machines.

After doing this, I had to delete and re-add the Apple IDs to Xcode, so that it could find their teams again. I didn't notice any other problems.

Answer (score 2):

- First delete them from the Apple Developer Site.
- Do not allow Xcode to manage it via **Automatic** option (*most important thing*). Always choose provisionings you create manually in Developer Site.:

[image]

- you may remove them via **Accounts Preferences** (right click on item -> Move to Trash):

[image]

Comment: I did the Move to Trash step. I'll take your advice about not using Automatic selection, but right now I don't have any projects open, and it's still re-creating my deleted profiles.

Comment: The first and third steps are obvious, but for others